# How to trigger event for `never` operator in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

When a user taps button, my viewModel needs to execute some tasks, such as resigning first responder (keyboard). I presume the best way is to set up a trigger in my ViewModel, that the ViewController will observe. Seems like a good time to use an `observable` `output` that doesn't emit any values like so:

`var resignFirstResponder = Observable<Any>.never()`

how do I emit new event for ViewController to listen to?

Answer (score 1):

*.never()* will obviously never emit anything. as far as i could understand your problem, *PublishSubject* is what you need.